# Android Libraries and custom xml attributes

Tags: android, listview, libraries, styleable

I want to use a library to make drag and drop list view. It's named "drag-sort-list-view"
After download this lib project,I created a project and I exported de libray folder in .jar, including the .classes and the xml dslv_attrs, containing the styleable. I can't compile with it. Look at my xml where i want to use the custom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mobeta.android.dslv"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    dslv:drag_enabled="true"
    dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
    dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
    dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
    dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
    dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
    dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
    dslv:use_default_controller="true"
    dslv:drag_handle_id="@id/drag_handle"
    dslv:sort_enabled="true"
    dslv:remove_enabled="true"
    dslv:drag_start_mode="onDown"
    dslv:remove_mode="flingRemove" />
```

for the line xmlns:dslv , if I set my package project I have this kind of error :

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xxx' in package
```

Every where i read it's the fix of the issue...

When I set the library project, like on the example, it compile and stop with this error in the logcat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.interfacevm/com.example.interfacevm.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML 
                                  file line #2: Error inflating class com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
```

I read that there 'is a fix for this issur in sdk 17, but it doesn't work for me. An idea ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's just a guess, but try to replace the namespace with

```
xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

That's how i import my libraries and that works fine.

Comment: The problem stay the same. Are your librairies define styleable ?

Comment: Yes, the library contains custom styleables. Though, i'm not exporting it, but rather keep it as a project in eclipse. Try if that helps. Keep it as a project in eclipse, set the android library flag, reference it from your main project and run it. that should work.

Comment: Ah ok it was the situation I had at the beginning : two project, one named library. I want to export library in a .jar to add it in my launcher project, but I have the issue of the question.